# Register a custom AttributeBag to the SessionManager

Tags: sessions

How can I register a new custom AttributeBag into the session manager? I have this custom module and want to contain the session stuff in a specific attributeBag.

But when I try to call the registerBag() method from my code I get an error that it's not possible due to the session already being started.

Can I hook into the session manager service from my service container definition file? The session manager does not seem to support a service_collector.

Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way of storing user specific information to the session is using the user's private tempstore. You don't have to go down to the attribute bags.

You can access this tempstore through the `user.private_tempstore` service:

```
// Get tempstore. Within classes use dependency injection instead.
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name');
// Set my_variable_name.
$tempstore->set('my_variable_name', $data);
```

You can then retrieve the values again from session by using the get method:

```
// Get tempstore. Within classes use dependency injection instead.
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name');
// Get my_variable_name data.
$data = $tempstore->get('my_variable_name');
```

Please note, that the private tempstore is available for logged-in users only, not for an anonymous session. (An according core change request to allow anonymous session private tempstore is [in review](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2743931).)

Comment: I need it for any request, not just logged in users. So this will not cover my needs.